# How to get all the elements from the HTML document using Jsoup Library?

Tags: android, html, jsoup

I'm trying to parse the HTML tag using `Jsoup library`. I want to iterate over through all the elements. and replace `"\br"` with a `""`. I using the below method:

```
 private void parseHtmlDoc(Document doc){
        StringBuilder builder;
        List<String> descriptionList=new ArrayList<String>();
         builder=new StringBuilder();
        Elements elementList=doc.getAllElements();
        for(Element element:elementList){
            if(element.equals(doc.select("\r\n"))){
                builder.append(element.text());
                builder.append("\n");
                Log.d("HTML",builder.toString());
            }

            else if(element.equals(doc.select("<img>"))){
                if(builder.length()!=0) {
                    String text = builder.toString();
                    descriptionList.add(text);
                    Log.d("HTML", text);
                }

                 builder=new StringBuilder();

            }

        }
```

But my app is crashing at this line:

```
   for(Element element:elementList)
```

I'm I doing anything wrong here...Please help me to fix this problem.

Updated Code:

I changed the implementation to the below code:

```
 Elements elements=doc.getElementsByTag("html");
        for(Element element:elements){
            Log.d("HTML",element.text());
        }
```

Now, I'm getting all the tags inside the element. This element has internal tags like,

, 
 <\n> . I want to iterate through each tag and replace them. I'm stuck at this point. I don't know how to get the child elements from the Html tag.

Comment: Just to clarify do you mean that you want to replace `<br/>` tags? (vs. "\br")

Comment: yes..I want to replce tags such as "<p></p>","<br><br/>" with a new line. I updated my code. Plz check.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do completely, but maybe this will give you a general direction:

```
    Document doc;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br").get();
        String htmlNoBr  = doc.html().replaceAll("<br>", "");
        System.out.println(htmlNoBr);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The code above replaces **all** "< br>" occurances within html with empty strings and returns the result to htmlNoBr String object.

In case you want to remove all "< br>" that create a line break, which I assume you do. You should ignore all "< br>" tags that accure whitin "< pre>" tags like so:

```
private static final String PRE_TAG = "pre";

public static void  parseHtmlDoc(Document doc) {
    Elements elementList = doc.getAllElements();
    for (Element element : elementList) {

        //if the tag isn't <pre> add it to new elements collection
        if(element.tag().toString().compareTo(PRE_TAG) != 0)
        {
            element.text(element.text().replaceAll("<br>", ""));

        }

    }

}
```

Hope this helps.
Also, next time your code crashes, add the crash log to your question.

[update]
To answer your question in the comment, this is one way you can iterate over all elements and their child elements:

```
    public static void recurseOverElements(Elements elementList){

    if(elementList.size() == 0)
        return;

    for (Element element : elementList) {

        recurseOverElements(element.children());
        System.out.println("element tag = " + element.tagName());
    }


}
```

[update 2]
Use this code to call the function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Document doc;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br").get();
        //Create a new empty elements collection
        Elements allElementsInDom = new Elements();
        //send to a method that recurses over all child elements and adds them to the new collection
        recurseOverElements(doc.getAllElements(), allElementsInDom);

        //Iterate over all the elements and their child elements from the DOM
        for (Element element : allElementsInDom) {
            System.out.println(element.tagName());
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

and these are the changes made to the method above:

```
/*
 * Iterates over all elements and child elements in elementList
 * Returns allChildElemets collections with all nested elements 
 */
public static Elements recurseOverElements(Elements elementList, Elements allChildElemets){
    if(elementList.size() == 0)
        return allChildElemets;

    for (Element element : elementList) {

        recurseOverElements(element.children(), allChildElemets);
        allChildElemets.add(element);
    }
    return allChildElemets;
}
```

I don't know if there is a better way, but this is how I would do it.

Comment: is there way to get the nested tags from the element. In my case, element has many inner tags, I want to iterate through each tag.

Comment: Elements elementList = doc.getAllElements(); gives entire document conents into a single element. I want each tag to come as individual element

Comment: I don't know if there is a "better practice" way for doing that. Having said that , take a look at the recurseOverElements function I added to my answer. It Gives you all child elements as individual elements. You can make that function return a new Elements object. instead of the priniting line just add elements to it and return it at the end.  see updated answer (update2)

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. But As, I said, I'm getting all element list. But every Element contains the entire html body.